# How to prevent my photobanner from getting cut off on webpage, and to get an automatic scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, photo

I have photobanners (a series of photos lined horizontally) on my web-pages and if they were very long in width I used to be able to just scroll horizontally through them, and there would be a scrollbar at the bottom clearly indicating that the web-page is long. Now I've gone and erased some code in the process of doing something else, but now realised that the photobanners are just cut off by the width/size of the webpage itself and there's no natural scrollbar at the bottom anymore. I'd like to restore it to the way it was before.

I tried forcing a scrollbar in there with `html {overflow: scroll;}` but the scrollbar on that webpage was just "full" even though the photobanner was still veering off to the right. I also tried adding `overflow: scroll;` or `:auto;` to the photobanner itself but that achieved a bad result. And, adding `width: 100%;` to the `html` div did not appear to do anything.

this is the `CSS` I believe is relevant:

```
#container1 {
width: 4000px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 100px auto;
background: none;
}

/*header*/
header1 {
width: 1800px;
margin: -400px;
}

header1 h1 {
text-align: justify;
font: 100 60px/1.5 roboto condensed;

}

header1 p {
font: 100 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
}

/*photobanner*/

.photobanner {
 height: 233px;
 width: 8550px;
 margin-left: -400px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 }

 .photobanner img {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 .photobanner img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
 -o-transform: scale(1.05);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
 transform: scale(1.05);
 cursor: pointer;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }
```

and the `html` :

```
<div id="container">
<div style="float: top;">
<div style="margin-top: -475px;">
<div class="photobanner"><img alt="" class="first" height="575" src="LINK" 
/><img alt="" height="575" src="LINK" /><img alt="" height="575" src="LINK" 
/><img alt="" height="575" src="LINK" /><img alt="" height="575" src="LINK" 
/>
<p>___</p>
<h1>HEADER</h1>
<p>CATPION</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT (1/4/19): Okay, so I tested things out by erasing random sections of my HTML temporarily and looking for what happened. Turns out when I removed the code where I planned to build my header upon:

```
<body class='section-1'>
<div id='menu'>
<div class='container'>
<div align="center"><a href="https://terrichienyi.com/"><img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/37c178aaab3ceab836b8136297132679/tumblr_pjqt2u 
lQ8R1xmt4ilo5_1280.png"></a>

<a href="https://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="http://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="https://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="https://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="https://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="https://google.com/in/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><a 
href="http://google.com/" target=blank><img 
src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1suoTg5qAXuNjy1Xdq6yYcVXaq/14inch-button- 
interface-small-size-color-tv.jpg_50x50.jpg"></a><br />
</div>
```

The problem with the photobanner just magically fixed itself. May anyone explain why this happens? What in this text is suddenly blocking my webscreen from being scrolled through? I would still like to keep the header while still not having to deal with this issue.

edit(1/11/2019): Re-ordering the HTML above to a different part of the overall HTML does not work either, and sometimes it scrambles the header. Only removing it entirely fixes the problem, but I want a way for my header to safely remain and appear identical to the way it does now.

Comment: In what way was it a "bad result" when you added `overflow: scroll` to `.photobanner`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the scrollbar would be put directly under the photos instead of the whole page, and more importantly the bar wouldn't budge.

Comment: Are you saying that the scrollbar for the page (i.e. at the bottom of the browser window) only scrolled the photobanner div and the rest of the content stayed in place?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, what I'm saying is that it doesn't scroll at all, or indicate that there is even content to the far right. You know how there's a bar to drag through a trough(?) depending on the size of the page? Well the bar fills the trough entirely and doesn't move even though my photobanner is longer than the computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width property

Instead of using 'width', use 'max-width' it will help you get the complete width of the browser window and will be responsive.

CSS -->

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, under what property should I add this? I put `max-width: 100%` under `.photobanner` and then a `html` , and both instances just squashed the individual images themselves. Or should I use it to replace?

Comment: Add it to .photobanner

Comment: it caused the same result, unfortunately.